# NodeJs >Express > AWS > S3 > getting emplty res.send() intested of object probably a Promise delay

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to work with, I am getting the object in console.log(data,"MongoData--->")  but getting the empty object as a response in clint side

```
Promise {
  { _id: 5f44ed71ae6ebea2d14a9808,
  name: 'https://rsboost.s3.amazonaws.com/sn3-1598352752273.png' } } 'MongoData--->'
```

RouteFile

```
router.post("/",async function(req, res, next){
 ImgUpload(req, res,(error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("errors", error);
      res.json({ error: error });
    } else {
      // If File not found
      if (req.file === undefined) {
        console.log("Error: No File Selected!");
        res.json("Error: No File Selected");
      } else {
        // If Success
       const imageLocation = req.file.location; // Save the file name into database into File model
       const data = await CreateFile({name:imageLocation})
       console.log(data,"MongoData--->")
       res.json(data)
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Aws Function returning correct data

```
const ImgUpload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "*****",
    acl: "public-read",
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(
        null,
        path.basename(file.originalname, path.extname(file.originalname)) +
          "-" +
          Date.now() +
          path.extname(file.originalname)
      );
    },
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 20000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 20 MB
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
}).single("fileImage");
```

Problem: getting the desired response with data but under-promise, Need help to write promise as I tried async-await but it's not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is `CreateFile()`?

Comment: Its a modal function retrieving data from MongoDB, that's what delaying under Promis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by myself > in route file > .then()=> is the solution for waiting for the promise, little thing I missed

```
const data = CreateFile({ name: imageLocation }).then((data) => {
 res.send(data);
  });
```